# scan business card address using dessert library but getting a linking error

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm getting following linking error when compiled.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetUTF8Text()", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract recognizedText] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetVariable(char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract setVariableValue:forKey:] in Tesseract.o
      -[Tesseract loadVariables] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int, GenericVector<STRING> const*, GenericVector<STRING> const*, bool)", referenced from:
      tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*) in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Version()", referenced from:
      +[Tesseract version] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetImage(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract setImage:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Recognize(ETEXT_DESC*)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract recognize] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract initWithDataPath:language:] in Tesseract.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

/Users/admin/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-02-04 at 3.38.46 pm.png

how to resolve it.. or any other library that supports in iOS8...?

Comment: You are missing the tesseract library as dependency.

Comment: trried to add that but it also not for the iOS8. if you have the dependencies compiled file please send me..

Comment: I don't have that myself. I did compile tesseract myself for OS X using gyp (so I can use it as static library). It's not hard. Just get the latest released source of tesseract, and start making it a static library product in xcode. good luck.